# How to query a timezone data type in oracle using the java time format

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have the below timestamp with timezone data stored in  a table

```
create table sample(id number,last_modified_dt timestamp with time zone);

select last_modified_dt from sample;

last_modified_dt
-----------------
19-06-17 09:36:28.100452000 AM +00:00
```

My front end node.js application is trying to query using the below format,

```
'2017-06-19T09:36:28Z' (java timestamp format)


select last_modified_dt from sample where last_modified_dt = '2017-06-19T09:36:28Z'
```

i tried using

```
select last_modified_dt from sample where last_modified_dt = TO_TIMESTAMP('2017-06-19T09:36:28Z','YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS"Z"');
```

but it returns empty result, clearly i know something is missing, can you please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution, but a very quick solution is 
if you always get the time in that format

```
   select last_modified_dt from sample 
    where TRUNC(last_modified_dt) = 
          TRUNC(to_date (regexp_replace ('2017-06-19T09:36:28Z',
                   '[a-zA-Z]',' '),
           'rrrr-mm-dd hh:mi:ss')) -- TRUNC can be added if only date is important for matching and time is not important.
```

REGEXP_REPLACE will remove occurrences of any character from the timestamp which you get from Java.

a-ZA-Z will make sure, all English Alphabets are removed.

if db format is `dd-mm-yyyy`, only if date is being stored as characters

```
select last_modified_dt from sample 
where TRUNC(last_modified_dt) = 
      TRUNC(to_date (regexp_replace ('2017-06-19T09:36:28Z',
               '[a-zA-Z]',' '),
       'rrrr-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'))
```

Comment: Hmm, thanks for the comment, but still it is not working as the db format is dd-mm-yyyy and the input is yyyy-mm-dd. Is there a way to convert the timestamp with time zont to date format?

Comment: @AnishGopinath I don't think that makes any difference, what you see from your SQL client may have a different format. when you convert your input using `TO_DATE` it should match to oracle without a problem. `dd-mm-yyyy` might be something you are seeing on your SQL Client as per your settings.

Comment: monda: im getting ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string error

Comment: Updated the answer, Also the proper usage of comments is to add the user to whom you are referring to @AnishGopinath and to spell it right as well :)

Comment: I am pretty sure it must be `hh24` instead of `hh`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes, if they have a 24 hours format. not sure, what they are doing on the application side, if its a 24 hours format or a 12 hour format. I agree, `am` should have been added

Comment: Thanks it works, any other way to fetch the values , it is used in search scenario, that too on a large base, it is taking time.

Comment: It would be **very** strange to use the [ISO format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with 12 hour format.

Comment: @SudiptaMondal :Is it possible to fetch using the date and timestamp instead of date alone?

Comment: @AnishGopinath - yes, just remove the `TRUNC`

Comment: nop, it is not, consider i have a series of values(timestamp with timezone dataytpe) starts from 4 in the moring, if i remove truc and nothing is getting displayed, if i put >= then all date are getting displayed from the start of the day, even if i put last_modified_dt >=
      TO_TIMESTAMP (regexp_replace ('2017-06-19T09:36:28Z',
               '[a-zA-Z]',' '),
       'rrrr-mm-dd hh:mi:ss'). It is fetching records from 2017-06-19 04:50:53.562194000 AM +00:00

Comment: i believe it is considering the FF value of `19-06-17 09:36:28.100452000 AM +00:00. ` That is why the equal is not working, i tried using to_date, cast function, it is not working. The query looks fine, except it has to consider only yyyy-mm-dd hH24:MI:SS